# Failed to parse date

Tags: c++, date, time, format

I have this code:

```
std::tm tm{};
std::istringstream str_stream("Wed"); // date
str_stream >> std::get_time(&tm, "%a"); // format date
std::time_t time = std::mktime(&tm); // equals -1
```

Also it do not work with "Sep" and %b, i. e. it do not work with chars.
What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I don't think `"Wed"` is a valid date.  Which `Wed` would it use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you inspect the contents of `tm` it should be what you expect.

`get_time` with `%a` will parse into `tm_wday`.

However `mktime` does not use `tm_wday` and `tm_yday` at all, using the other fields exclusively. Infact, `mktime` actually **sets** those fields (this is why the tm input can not be `const`) based on the others.

Thus you are effectively passing a bunch of zeros to it, notably `tm_year`, and with `time_t` on many plaforms being seconds since 1970, and allthough often signed, they consider times before 1970 invalid.

For example with MSVC, `time_t` is a 64bit signed integer, but [mktime is documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d1y53h2a.aspx) to only be valid for "January 1, 1970 to 23:59:59, December 31, 3000"

Comment: I did check it with date "Tue, 15 Nov 2010 08:12:31 GMT". But all fields in `tm` are zero.

Comment: `tm_wday` before mktime should be 3. I am not sure if `mktime` will overwrite it on failure, but it definately would on success. If you want to get a time for say midnight for a day of the current week, you will need to combine it with the other values (like a proper `tm_year` and `tm_mon`, then find the `tm_mday` for the first day of the week, then do `tm_mday += tm_wday` to adjust it)

Comment: When I checked it, I did not call `mktime`.

Comment: Which compiler was that? Also if you were running the program with a non-English locale, then you need to replace "Wed" with the correct localised version, or change the locale.

Comment: I set locale to `std::locale::global(std::locale(""))` and use MSVC.

Comment: I think for MSVC `""` is the user/environment default locale, use `"C"` or [`locale::classic`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1w3527e2.aspx#locale::classic)

Comment: With `locale::classic` it works. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Your call will probably write successfully into `t->tm_wday`, yet when using [mktime](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/mktime) afterwards, the value in `time->tm_wday` is ignored:

> **std::mktime**
>
> ...
>   time->tm_wday and time->tm_yday are ignored. The values in time are
>   permitted to be outside their normal ranges. ...

Hence, everything you write into `tm` is ignored, the result cannot be represented as `time_t`, and the return value is thus `-1`.

In contrast to `mktime`, `std::put_time` uses the respective values, but reinterprets them for the output (such that `February` might turn into `Feb`):

```
int main ()
{
    std::tm t = {};
    istringstream ss("Thursday February");
    ss >> std::get_time(&t, "%a %b");
    if (ss.fail()) {
        cout << "invalid date value." << endl;
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "Date: " << std::put_time(&t, "%a %b") << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Date: Thu Feb
```

Comment: When I run you example, I get: `invalid date value.`. It really strange.